# How to add a toolbar to a TableView in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, toolbar

I am building a simple notes application and I want to add a static bar at the bottom of the TableView. For example, I want to add a help button. How can I do this to just my TableView?

So far:

I have added a toolbar through storyboard, but that makes it stick at the end of the last made tableView cell. I want it stuck to the bottom. I entered this code to do programmatically:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

in my tableViewController.h file and

```
[self.view addSubview:_toolbar];
[self.navigationController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
```

in my tableViewController.m file in my `viewDidLoad` method

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution is to use a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController. (This has been said above, but let me give you the details).

Create a new UIViewController with it's respective XIB. Inside your new UIViewController's view drag in a UITableView, resize it, and drag your UIToolbar wherever you want.

You should have something like this:

[image]

The black border represents the UIViewController's main view. The red border represents the table view. The blue border represents your toolbar.

Afterwards, make your UIViewController comply with two protocols: UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. You will manually have to implement it's essential methods such us cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection, etc, but it shouldn't take you long.

Link your UITableView to your UIViewController. Link it's "data source" and "delegate" properties to the view controller as well.

You will have your setup ready in less than 15 minutes.

Comment: Good answer, I think so!

Answer (score 8):

I just found a better trick!

1. Make sure there is NO Navigation Bar (from your failed attempts)
2. Drag and drop a "Bar Button Item" (Xcode will magically place it for you at the bottom)
3. **NOTE**: If you Run the App now you won't see anything! (so keep reading)
4. Add the following line of code under viewDidLoad:

   self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

Done!

Comment: nice - if you dont want them on the other views just set to false ... now that we use swift

Comment: Nice trick !!. I wonder why the toolbar goes to the bottom by default. Does it not conflict with Apple HIG? For swift use self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false

Answer (score 3):

You can use a standard UITableViewController with a storyboard. In "simulated metrics", go to the Bottom Bar menu and select "Toolbar". The toolbar appears. You can then add button items to it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. So simple. I have been using this method for years. Why are people making such a big deal out of this? Providing such convoluted answers!

Answer (score 1):

Add a toolbar via codes is simple.

```
UIToolbar *toobar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:frameYouNeed];
toobar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self.view addSubview:toobar];
```

But it would be better if you use UITableView as a subView, rather than a UITableViewController

Comment: just as @Leonnears said, make the toolbar and tableView as two subViews of your viewController

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ViewController` instead of `TableViewController`

Then make your `TableView` as a IBOutlet in your header file. Declare delegate and data source. You are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toolbar that is included in all UITableViews by default, and add UIBarButtonItems to it. Despite the name, UIBarButtonItems can be customized to be any kind of view. Then you add them to the property self.toolbarItems, which is available to UITableViews by default. 
e.g.

```
UIBarButtonItem * textItem;
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 48)];
label.text =  @"ImportantText";
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
textItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithCustomView:label];

UIBarButtonItem * switchItem;
UISwitch * switchCtrl = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[switchCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
switchItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithCustomView:switchCtrl];

self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                     textItem,switchItem,nil ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in a Storyboard by checking Show Toolbar in the Navigation Controller. Then dragging Bar Button Items to the greyed out toolbar area now shown at the bottom of the Table View Controller. Then wiring the Bar Button Items up to methods Navigation Controller.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, It will add your toolbar as footerView of the table. and make sure you have give footer height of the table as 44(height of the toolbar).

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = _toolbar;
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: That just sticks toolbar under tableView not bottom of the screen.