# Swift: Adding a toolbar and tool bar button item to a Table View

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am unable to add a tool bar to my tableView using the Xcode main.storyboard.
Thus, I tried coding it in manually in the viewDidLoad()

```
    let logOutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log Out", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "logOut")
    var bottomBarButtonArray = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    bottomBarButtonArray.append(logOutButton)

    self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

    self.navigationController!.toolbar.items = bottomBarButtonArray
```

May I know how do I set the logOutButton text and also how to detect if logOutButton has been pressed.

I tried `logOutButton.description = "Log Out"` but it does not work.

My toolbar does appear but I have no idea how to add the text for the logout button.
[image]

Comment: See this : [How to add ToolBar button to Tool Bar in my Navigation Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943951/how-to-add-toolbar-button-to-tool-bar-in-my-navigation-controller).

Comment: Agree with @ksa_coder

Comment: The solution that ksa_coder linked to me works but I really want to learn how to do it programmatically as well. I have already tried that link before asking but it does not work for me. I could add it to the top navigation bar but not the bottom one. It does not appear no matter what I did. I have been working on it for 2 days straight now and I am very new to swift. Please show me where i went wrong. I really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am away from my mac..try this : [Swift UIToolBar Append UIBarButtonItem Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715930/swift-uitoolbar-append-uibarbuttonitem-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use UIViewController as parent class and not UITableViewController

[How to add a toolbar to a TableView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061251/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-a-tableview-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

If the TableView happens to be embedded in a Navigation Controller, there is an easy solution: you can add the Toolbar straight away in the NavigationController. The checkbox 'Shows Toolbar' in the Attributes Inspector is all you need. 
Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832688/5897915